# Null value with get method of hashtable

Tags: java, hash, get, hashtable

I have written the following Java program.this program splits the given sentence and tags each word with its parts of speech using standard pos tagger.I have hashed each parts of speech tag with a number in a hash set pos_tag_numb.

I got the correct parts of speech for each word,however when i am tring to get tag number from the hash table ,i get a null value.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.TaggedWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;



class maindemo
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        //if(args.length<1) {
            //System.err.println("Usage: java SentiWordNetDemoCode <pathToSentiWordNetFile>");
            //return;
        //}

        String pathToSWN = "D:\\Acad !!\\Project_idrbt\\home\\swn\\www\\admin\\dump\\SentiWordNet_3.0.0_20130122.txt";
        MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("D:\\Acad !!\\Project_idrbt\\stanford-postagger-2014-01-04\\models\\english-left3words-distsim.tagger");

        //hashing each pos tag to a number
        Hashtable<String,Integer> pos_tag_numb = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
        pos_tag_numb.put("JJ",2);
        pos_tag_numb.put("JJR",2);
        pos_tag_numb.put("JJS",2);

        pos_tag_numb.put("RB",5);
        pos_tag_numb.put("RBR",5);
        pos_tag_numb.put("RBS",5);
        pos_tag_numb.put("WRB",5);


        SentiWordNetDemoCode sentiwordnet = new SentiWordNetDemoCode(pathToSWN);

        String review="very good little bad";

        String[] tokens=review.split(" ");

        int ti=0;


        for(String s: tokens)
        {
            String taggedstring=tagger.tagString(s);
            String[] word_pos_pair=taggedstring.split("_");
            String pos=new String(word_pos_pair[1]);

            System.out.println(word_pos_pair[0]+"  "+ pos_tag_numb.get( pos ) );
        }


    }
}
```

tagger.tagString(s) gives an output of for WORD_POSTAG,Eg: very_RB ,good_JJ

If i add the line System.out.println("tag is  "+pos);  at line 54 output is

> > tag is  RB
> >
> > very  null
> >
> > tag is  JJ
> >
> > good  null
> >
> > tag is  RB
> >
> > little  null
> >
> > tag is  JJ
> >
> > bad  null

Comment: Did you try to print `pos` ?

Comment: yeah,it gave me correct output

Comment: What is current output of your program, can you please put it here?

Comment: Something there `String taggedstring=tagger.tagString(s);` Because when manually set `String[] word_pos_pair=taggedstring.split("_");` like `String[] word_pos_pair="very_RB".split("_");` work fine.

Comment: Can you add a System.out.println("POS="+pos); just after initializing pos and tell what it prints?

Comment: @Raghu i have added the output in my question..sorry for the delay

Comment: Thanks @disable1992 ...got the hint from you and solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally i solved my own problem,i guess the method tagger.tagString() is returning a string with some trailing spaces..i just added one statement

> > taggedstring= taggedstring.trim();

before i split the string i.e before the statement

> > String[] word_pos_pair=taggedstring.split("_");